# How do i add an index in jq

Tags: jq

I want to use jq map my input

```
["a", "b"]
```

to output

```
[{name: "a", index: 0}, {name: "b", index: 1}]
```

I got as far as

```
0 as $i | def incr: $i = $i + 1; [.[] | {name:., index:incr}]'
```

which outputs:

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "index": 1
  }
]
```

But I'm missing something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's easier than you think.

```
to_entries | map({name:.value, index:.key})
```

`to_entries` takes an object and returns an array of key/value pairs. In the case of arrays, it effectively makes index/value pairs.  You could map those pairs to the items you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

A more "hands-on" approach is to use `reduce`:

`["a", "b"] | . as $in | reduce range(0;length) as $i ([]; . + [{"name": $in[$i], "index": $i}])`

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few more ways. Assuming `input.json` contains your data

```
["a", "b"]
```

and you invoke jq as

```
jq -M -c -f filter.jq input.json
```

then any of the following `filter.jq` filters will generate

```
{"name":"a","index":0}
{"name":"b","index":1}
```

1) using **keys** and **foreach**

```
   foreach keys[] as $k (.;.;[$k,.[$k]])
 | {name:.[1], index:.[0]}
```

EDIT: I now realize a filter of the form `foreach E as $X (.; .; R)` can almost always be rewritten as `E as $X | R` so the above is really just

```
   keys[] as $k
 | [$k, .[$k]]
 | {name:.[1], index:.[0]}
```

which can be simplified to

```
   keys[] as $k
 | {name:.[$k], index:$k}
```

2) using **keys** and **transpose**

```
   [keys, .]
 | transpose[]
 | {name:.[1], index:.[0]}
```

3) using a function

```
 def enumerate:
    def _enum(i):
      if   length<1
      then empty
      else [i, .[0]], (.[1:] | _enum(i+1))
      end
    ;
    _enum(0)
  ;

   enumerate
 | {name:.[1], index:.[0]}
```

Comment: `keys` involves the construction of an array, so it would be more efficient here to use `range(0;length)`.

Comment: Unable to understand your option for jq -M -c -f filter.jq input.json. what does filter,jq contain???

Comment: @Devesh `filter.jq` could be any of the three examples I gave. The first example 1) used **keys** and **foreach**.  The second example 2) used **keys** and **transpose**.  The third example 3) defined an enumerate function.

Answer (score 0):

This should also do the trick:

```
[range(length) as $i | .[$i] | {name: ., index: $i}]
```

jqplay [here](https://jqplay.org/s/sS8mfkWZiuO).