# How to "number" array items?

Tags: json, jq

Considering input:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 2
  },
  {
    "a": 7
  }
]
```

how do I add new field to each object, which value would be index in array? Producing:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "index": 0
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 7,
    "index": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: This Q has other answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528256/how-do-i-add-an-index-in-jq

Comment: sorry, I didn't find that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the structure into a variable, then use `keys` to get the indices, retrieve the corresponding object from the variable using the index and add the index to it:

```
jq '[ . as $d | keys[] | $d[.] + {index:.} ]' file.json
```

Comment: `keys` requires the construction of an array, so using `range(0;length)` here would be more efficient, and potentially much more so.

Answer (score 3):

Using `reduce`, without disassembling/reassembling the input:

```
reduce range(length) as $index (.; .[$index] += {$index})
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9rmU_bulwH)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

`to_entries` takes an object and returns an array of key/value pairs.
It can be used effectively and intuitively.

- [jq/to_entries](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries)

#### input file

```json
// file.json
[
    {
      "a": 1
    },
    {
      "a": 2
    },
    {
      "a": 7
    }
]
```

#### commands

```
jq 'to_entries | map(.value+{index:.key})' file.json
```

#### results

```json
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "index": 0
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 7,
    "index": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's also an alternative (non-jq) solution, using `jtc`:

```
bash $ <input.json jtc -w'[:]<I>k' -i'{"index":{I}}'
[
   {
      "a": 1,
      "index": 0
   },
   {
      "a": 2,
      "index": 1
   },
   {
      "a": 7,
      "index": 2
   }
]
bash $
```

PS. I'm a developer of `jtc` - unix JSON processor
PPS. The disclaimer is required by SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try : Array[index_of_object].property = value
for example : array[0].a = 1
```

Comment: sorry, I don't think this will work, this is doing smth completely different IIUC.